# iPhone indefinite background exectuion Xcode mystery

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, background-process

I am writing an app for personal use that needs continuous background execution. Apple tries to make this difficult, but I found that declaring that my app uses background location updates and then creating background task (with no content, just a blank task) allows my app to run indefinitely when I run the project from Xcode. I do not understand why this works. I noticed that after about three minutes, when presumably the task is supposed to be terminated, I get the following error:

> Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 174256fe0, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

After this message, the app continues to run in the background normally. So, it seems that this indefinite execution is a bit of an exploit, which I'm fine with because I just want to make the app work.

However, when I run the app from the phone (i.e. not pressing the run button in my Xcode project), the background execution seems to stop after 3 minutes. This is a problem, and I can't seem to figure out why execution continues in one case but not in the other. What is the difference between running an app normally and running it through Xcode? Is there a simpler or better way to get the indefinite background execution I'm looking for given that I'm not trying to get this app published to the app store?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not submitting to the store - why not try this:

Enable the app for background audio services. Then, just play  a silent audio file in the background on a constant loop?

Comment: that's really clever, I hope I can find a reason to use that at some point

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you are running through Xcode. Normal background limits are removed when running through the debugger.